# Pagination on Update-ListView

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have written a `PowerShell script` as an action to delete selected items in the list view.

The issue is - when I delete an item on any page other than the first one, after deletion, `update-listview` command returns to page 1. What is the command to make it stick to that particular page from where the item has been deleted?

[image]